# Ethernet problems not connecting to router

Tags: ethernet

i have ethernet wall jacks and i just moved rooms.I have my ethernet plugged into my ATT router and the ethernet jack from my room into my computer but it is picking up a netgear ethernet connection and not my ATT. I dont know why it would be picking up a different ethernet connection. any help?

Comment: Sound like you need to physically trace where all the cables go - where does the wall jack connect to?

Comment: the closet. I checked and made sure the cable is to the ATT modem, which it is. and i am still getting a netgear ethernet connection not ATT